# Complex Nested JSON in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to loop through nested JSON using swift, but I am able to retrieve records that are not nested. I can not retrieve the nested records.  I have also tried valueForKeyPath but it does not work.

This is what I have done at the moment:

Here is the JSON:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":"001",
      "firstName":"Fred",
      "lastName":"Blogs",
      "role":"Producer"
   },
   {  
      "teamName":"A",
      "members":[  
         {  
            "id":"002",
            "firstName":"Michael",
            "lastName":"Right",
            "role":"Cook"
         },
         {  
            "id":"003",
            "firstName":"James",
            "lastName":"Brown",
            "role":"Bus Driver"
         },
         {  
            "id":"004",
            "firstName":"Liam",
            "lastName":"Nelson",
            "role":"Actor"
         },
         {  
            "id":"005",
            "firstName":"Chris",
            "lastName":"Tucker",
            "role":"Actor"
         },
         {  
            "id":"006",
            "firstName":"Richard",
            "lastName":"Burton",
            "role":"Golfer"
         },
         {  
            "id":"007",
            "firstName":"Matt",
            "lastName":"Smith",
            "role":"Care Taker"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "teamName":"B",
      "members":[  
         {  
            "id":"008",
            "firstName":"Mark",
            "lastName":"Jones",
            "role":"Script Writter"
         },
         {  
            "id":"009",
            "firstName":"Hello",
            "lastName":"World",
            "role":"Tester"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Here is the Swift Code:

```
func getJSON() {

    guard let url = URL(string: "http://www.somejson.json") else { return }
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as AnyObject

        guard let array = json as?[[String: Any]] else { return }

        var teams = [Team]()
        var team: Team
        var i = 0

        for items in array {

            team = Team()


            if let id  = items["id"] as? String {
                team.id = id
                print("id", team.id)
            }

            if let firstName  = items["firstName"] as? String {
                team.firstName = firstName
                print("FirstName", team.firstName)
            }


            if let lastName  = items["lastName"] as? String {
                team.lastName = lastName
                print("LastName", team.lastName)
            }


            if let role  = items["role"] as? String {
                team.role = role
                print("Role", team.role)
            }


            if let profileImageURL  = items["profileImageURL"] as? String {
                team.profileImageURL = profileImageURL
                print("ProfileImageURL", team.profileImageURL)
            }


            if let teamName  = items["teamName"] as? String {

                print("TeamName", teamName)

                //if let id = json?.value(forKeyPath:"members.id") {
                  //  print("Test", id)
                //}

            }

            teams.append(team)

    }

        print("Count", teams.count)

    } catch {

    }
}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend using 3rd party JSON parsing framework such as `SwiftyJSON`. It will unburden this kind of tasks. Even there's `Codable` protocol, this kind of framework will give a lot more flexibility.

Comment: Use Swift 4.1 with the new codable protocol :}

Comment: The reason you failed to parse the JSON was that you didn't get items in `members` object.

Comment: When iterating over the array check if the dictionary has a key `teamName`. If yes, get the array of `members` and parse those, otherwise parse the *Producer* dictionary. It's highly recommended to update to Swift 4+. There it's very easy to parse JSON without extra libraries.

Comment: Ryan, Thanks for your reply.  I will look into SwiftJSON, although I really wanted to manipulate the JSON data using pure Swift code with no libraries.  Thanks.

Comment: You should not do this at all even if its an assignment. Learn the use of `Codable/Decodable` OR `SwifyJSON` or `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: Swift 4 is pure Swift code with no libraries. Use it. It's very silly not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Swift `Codable` protocol is the way to go. There are even online tools such as [Quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io) to get you started by generating Swift code from your JSON.

Example code for parsing your JSON:

```
// To parse the JSON, add this file to your project and do:
//
//   let teams = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Team].self, from: jsonData)

import Foundation

typealias Team = [TeamElement]

struct TeamElement: Codable {
    let id, firstName, lastName, role: String?
    let teamName: String?
    let members: [Member]?
}

struct Member: Codable {
    let id, firstName, lastName, role: String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to allow for the fact that the JSON structure has an item "members" containing the team members.

```
func getJSON() {

    guard let url = URL(string: "http://www.somejson.json") else { return }
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as AnyObject

        guard let array = json as?[[String: Any]] else { return }

        var teams = [Team]()
        for teamJson in array {
            var team = Team()

            if let members = teamJson["members"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                team.teamName = teamJson["teamName"] as! String
                for memberJson in members {
                    var member = Member()

                    if let id  = memberJson["id"] as? String {
                        member.id = id
                        print("id", member.id)
                    }

                    if let firstName  = memberJson["firstName"] as? String {
                        member.firstName = firstName
                        print("FirstName", member.firstName)
                    }


                    if let lastName  = memberJson["lastName"] as? String {
                        member.lastName = lastName
                        print("LastName", member.lastName)
                    }


                    if let role  = memberJson["role"] as? String {
                        member.role = role
                        print("Role", member.role)
                    }

                    team.members.append(member)
                }
            }

            teams.append(team)
        }

        print("Count", teams.count)

    } catch {
    }

}
```

You'll also have to write code to handle the outlier `producer` who is not in a team, but I'm sure you can work that out on your own. :)